# What is the error of saved frame using saveFrame()

Tags: processing

Using the code shown at http://processing.org/reference/saveFrame_.html I seem to be getting a grey overlay on every frame I try and output from any number of different sketchs? The grey bar overlay seems to grow as the more frame are saved. Has anyone else experienced this? Have I done something incorrect?

[image: two muppets]

Comment: The example code works fine for me without any grey bar showing up. Have you made any changes or additions to the code? If so, can you share them?

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield Here is the code. I think the only thing I changed was to add the save frame. It seems very strange that every thing I try saveframe() with has this problem. [http://pastebin.com/j54JW5j6](http://pastebin.com/j54JW5j6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that is doing this gray area in your sketch is this:

```
if (xport < 100) {
  line(xport, 0, xport, 100);
  xport = xport + 1;
}
```

I don't exactly know what you wanted to do, but its drawing a vertical line with xport as x and from 0 to 100 as y

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It was an oversight on my behalf as it is actually what is given in the example at http://processing.org/reference/saveFrame_.html Thanks